# Validating input in SFML's TGUI library

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a window where I have a couple of textboxes where people can enter their 
 first name, age, sex, job and any current illnesses and this gets saved to a text file.

I'm using SFML to make the window, handle background and other menu stuff and the TGUI library for the textboxes.

Following the tutorial on the TGUI website, I am able to get the text from a box and convert it to a string and the use, for example:

```
myfile << Job->getText().toAnsiString() << std::endl;
```

However, I need to validate the input such that, name is only one word, no special characters or numbers and Age is only an +ve int with no spaces or special characters, etc...

How do I go about doing this? In my newbie mind, for "age" for example, all I can think of is to have an array of special characters and [A-Z] and [a-z], and use a for loop to check each element in my string to each element in the array. But this seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it.
To limit the acceptable characters in the edit box you can simply use the [setInputValidator function](https://tgui.eu/documentation/v0.7/classtgui_1_1EditBox.html#a63373603e9d2e70d2f21766041712ade) which specifies the acceptable input. If you only want the user to type a number then just call the following function:

```
editBox->setInputValidator(tgui::EditBox::Validator::UInt);
```

The `setInputValidator` function can take a regex string as parameter so the validator can be as complex as you want to.

The second way is to do the verification manually afterwards (by going through all characters as in [Henri Prudhomme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382333)). This way you can allow the user to type incorrect content in the edit box and then e.g. change the color of the edit box to indicate that the value isn't valid.

The second way is better in more complex cases. Imagine you want to limit the input to a number between 10 and 20. You could do that with a regex in `setInputValidator`, but when the user starts typing a `1` with the intention to type another number after it, the input is rejected and nothing is added in the edit box. In such case the best way is probably a combination of both ways, let `setInputValidator` filter out all non-numeric input and then manually verify whether the number is within the wanted range afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to run a for loop through each of the strings and check that each character only falls within the ASCII range of the wanted characters.

For example if you want a name only contain Uppercase letters, you could type:

```
for(int I=0; I<name.length(); I++)
{
    if(!(name[I]>64 && name[I]<92))
    {
        cout << "Bad Name"
        flag = false;
    }
}
if(flag)
{
    cout << "Name is valid";
}
```

Look up an ASCII value chart to see what characters lie in which ranges.

If this answers your question, please mark it as your answer! Hope this helps.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Also, just looking at the ASCII value chart, I think `name[I]<92` should be `<91` and the former would still allow "[".

Comment: I would recommend to not use the ascii value directly, instead simply type the character: `if(!(name[I] >= 'A' && name[I] <= 'Z'))`. It is easier to understand the code that way.